# How to prevent the yellow background when a browser prepopulates fields?

Tags: css

Currently if the browser (chrome for instance) has a L&P saved for a sign in form, it prepopulates the values with an ugly yellow background for the input box.

Any idea what the CSS property is to override that to stay the default white?

Thanks

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate, he's not asking to keep the form from auto completing, he's asking to keep the style.

Comment: @Robert correct... I love auto complete. I don't love the yellow bkg

Comment: `-webkit-autofill` is the status it adds, I believe. You can try overriding that with !important. If you're looking for a pure CSS way, like implied.

Comment: I *want* my browser to indicate which fields it prepopulated ... are you looking for a way to change that behavior in *your own* browser, or a way to impose your preferences on *other people's* browsers?

Answer (score 1):

This article might be of use : http://www.quickonlinetips.com/archives/2007/07/how-to-remove-yellow-form-fields-background-color/

Basically it says its down to Google Toolbar and to fix it you can :

*In the installed Google Toolbar, select the “Settings” drop down menu (on the extreme right side) and click on “Options”. Under the large range of features, locate Autofill and click the “Autofill Settings” button. At the bottom you will find the Highlight option. Uncheck the box “Highlight fields on webpages that Autofill can update in Yellow” and press OK. Refresh your webpages and the yellow form field background is gone!*

hth

Comment: That's for the end user to do, not the web designer to do.

Comment: ...But this might be a possible solution, given that my browser (Firefox 5) doesn't do any sort of highlighting.  How do we know that AnApprentice's browser is just doing this because it's Chrome / has the Google Toolbar?